# c# deriving from int32

Tags: c#

i have several classes with members called 'Id'. Originally i wanted to store these as ints, but i would like some layer of protection, to make sure i don't accidentally assign a room id to a person etc.

one solution would be typedef (using RoomId = System.Int32;) but then i need that line of code in all files using these. i would prefer e.g. a RoomId class derived from int32, but i can't figure out how to set it up to allow explicit conversion (for initilisation)

or should i do this in some other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the only operation you really need is comparison for equality. You can create a RoomId class (or struct, whichever suits you)

```
class RoomId
{
    private int Value {get; set;}

    public RoomId(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public bool Equals(RoomId other)
    {
        return this.Value == other.Value;
    }
}

RoomId room1 = new RoomId(1);
RoomId room2 = new RoomId(2);

// To compare for equality
bool isItTheSameRoom = room1.Equals(room2);
// Or if you have overloaded the equality operator (==)
bool isItTheSameRoom = room1 == room2;
```

You can implement IEquatable, overload the equality and inequality operators if you want. If you need persistence, you could implement the ISerializable interface to make sure that the integer value only "escapes" the class if it is really needed.

Comment: excellent, thanks!

have a followup. since a need a couple of different id's, it seems like i should have a master ID class that does all this, and then just derive subIds. But this doesn't seem to work as i thought. 

renaming above to ID and writing 

public class ParticipantID : ID {}

gives an error: "ParticipantID does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument"

Comment: @second: The fallacy of having a master ID class is all child ID class instances will become implicitly castable to the master ID class, that is, comparable to each other. To solve the constructor issue, all you need to do is to have a "chain constructor", e.g public ParticipantID(int value) : base(value) { } - this would compile work, but your original aim of not being able to compare apples and oranges accidentally would not be achieved. The only way I can come up to fix it is by generics. See my code sample here: pastebin.com/m50aee5bf

Comment: awesome, thanks!
is this a common thing to do in this situation? or do people normally just use integers for ids and keep track themselves?

Comment: @second: Normally people just use integers (int, long or guid for 128-bit). While this is a "pure OO" approach, in my experience it is not necessary.

Answer (score 47):

You can't derive from `Int32`, but you can specify implicit conversions, which might give you the behaviour you need:

```
public struct RoomId
{
    private int _Value;

    public static implicit operator RoomId(int value)
    {
        return new RoomId { _Value = value };
    }

    public static implicit operator int(RoomId value)
    {
        return value._Value;
    }
}

// ...

RoomId id = 42;

Console.WriteLine(id == 41);    // False
Console.WriteLine(id == 42);    // True
Console.WriteLine(id < 42);     // False
Console.WriteLine(id > 41);     // True
Console.WriteLine(id * 2);      // 84
```

Comment: Great, certainly more concise than overriding every method and operator needed.

Comment: Great solution. I would also add an `IEquatable` implementation.

Comment: Although this looks very cool, in practice the safety of the static typing is compromised by the implicit casing.   The cast overload enables you to assign (or pass a parameter) to an int, but that's actually not what you want.   You don't want this to automatically "act like an int" because then you may pass it into the wrong place.   Only the lowest level code that actually needs the internal int should access it, and forcing it to call an explicit method or property such as Value will provide an additional level of type safety.

Answer (score 9):

```
 public static explicit operator RoomId(int value) {
     return new RoomId { Id = value };
 }
```

You could then do:

```
 RoomId variable = (RoomId)10;
```

It's not possible to derive a class from `Int32` or any other value type in C#.

Comment: do i then have to access it using myRoom.Id.id?

i would like it to work as if it was an int, ie just myRoom.Id, be able to compare them (which would compare their values etc)

Comment: No, myRoom.Id would work. You could also implement the equality comparer mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inherit value types (structs, including Int32) in .NET.

The closest option would be to make a struct which contained nothing but your Int32.  This would require the same space, but could be restricted to your exact struct.  You could then change your struct later to include other information, if needed.  (Be aware, though, that this will probably be a breaking API change.)

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to use a simple T4 template to generate custom types on the fly. Here's an example I used on a personal project recently. On line 10, is a list of types that are generated. Each of these things used to be `int`, but now they're strongly typed.

This also moves your code toward using a more Functional paradigm by avoiding the usual "primitive obsession" anti-pattern.

There's the template I'm using. Feel free to update/modify (let the rest of us know if you add anything useful).

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#

// List of types to generate:
var createTypeList = new[] { "XDim", "YDim", "YDelta", "DelayValue", "HValue", "Score", "TplIndexValue" };

#>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
// ReSharper disable CheckNamespace

<#
    for(int i = 0; i < createTypeList.Length; i++) 
    {
        var typeName = createTypeList[i];
#>

    [ImmutableObject(true)]
    public struct <#=typeName#> : IComparable<<#=typeName#>>
    {
        public <#=typeName#>(int value) { Value = value; }

        [Pure] public int Value { get; }
        [Pure] public bool Equals(<#=typeName#> other) => Value == other.Value;

        [Pure]
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (Equals(this, obj)) return true;
            return obj.GetType() == GetType() && Equals((<#=typeName#>)obj);
        }

        [Pure]
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (base.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ Value;
            }
        }

        [Pure] public static bool operator ==(<#=typeName#> left, <#=typeName#> right) => Equals(left, right);
        [Pure] public static bool operator !=(<#=typeName#> left, <#=typeName#> right) => !Equals(left, right);
        [Pure] public int CompareTo(<#=typeName#> other) => Equals(this, other) ? 0 : Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
        [Pure] public static bool operator <(<#=typeName#> left, <#=typeName#> right) => Comparer<<#=typeName#>>.Default.Compare(left, right) < 0;
        [Pure] public static bool operator >(<#=typeName#> left, <#=typeName#> right) => Comparer<<#=typeName#>>.Default.Compare(left, right) > 0;
        [Pure] public static bool operator <=(<#=typeName#> left, <#=typeName#> right) => Comparer<<#=typeName#>>.Default.Compare(left, right) <= 0;
        [Pure] public static bool operator >=(<#=typeName#> left, <#=typeName#> right) => Comparer<<#=typeName#>>.Default.Compare(left, right) >= 0;
        [Pure] public override string ToString() => $"{nameof(Value)}: {Value}";
    }
<#
    }
#>
```

Comment: I had actually never heard of T4 templating before your answer. Definitely glad I stumbled across it.

I made a small edit to fix a compilation error I was getting. Despite it being valid as far as I could tell, it didn't seem to like the way the constructor was set up, so I made it use the more traditional syntax.

Comment: Eagle-Eye, thank you for the contribution.   No issue on the code change, but to be honest, I'm not sure what exactly was your opposition.  If it was to the C#6 syntax, then I would have expected you to also change the Equals() method, as well as the rest of the methods at the bottom of the class.  Why single-out the constructor for using the different syntax in particular?   I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Like I said, the compiler was throwing errors with the constructor using the C#6 syntax, despite that being valid as far as I can tell. Intellisense says `public XDim(int value) => Value = value;` gives `'XDim.XDim(int)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial`, `Constructor must have body`, and `The name 'Value' does not exist in the current context.`, among others. Odd it has no problem with only the constructor. VS2015 and .NET Framework 4.6.1, if that helps narrow anything down.

Comment: Okay, well, I wish I could understand it.   My understanding of the language, as of C#6, that the following are the same: 1) `public XDim(int value) => Value = value;` and 2) `public XDim(int value) { Value = value; }`.   If the compiler has a problem with 1 and not 2, then how does it not have a problem with the rest of the class that uses C#6 syntax.   Very strange indeed.   Since I have no way of reproducing, I suppose we'll just leave at that.  Thanks for the fix.