# Can i extend type cast of common value types (like Int32) with implicid converter to my custom type?

Tags: c#, database

What if i need some kind of reference type wrapper for Int32 (the database Id for example). How can i convert Int32 to my class implicitly?

Comment: Why would you need a wrapper? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Just int32 or all common value types? Either use an implicit operator or implement IConvertible.

Comment: If all you need is an int that can be null, you can use `Nullable<int>` or `int?`.

Comment: Similar to -- but maybe not a dupe of -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850306/c-sharp-deriving-from-int32

Comment: i need it because of controlling value an it can change base type in future, so in purpose of some abstraction implementation i wish to wrap the value into it. I just forget that type cast can be declare backwards,  thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a static implicit converter operator:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ....
    static public implicit operator MyClass(int value)
    {
        // Create a new instance of your class using the value.
    }
    ...
}
```

Once created, you can do something like this:

```
MyClass myInstance = 48;
```

For more information, see MSDN: [Using Conversion Operators (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx)