# Own Types Based On Standard Types

Tags: c#

I want to have own types which are based on standard types.

For example I want to have type Dzeta, that will work as int.

So i want to write something like this:

```
Dzeta i = 0;
i++;
```

and so on.

Can somebody tell me how can i do such thing?

Comment: `struct`.  Google it.

Comment: Also, don't be lazy.  Type "for example' not "F.e.".  And "something" not "smth".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot derive from any value type (struct).
You can only create own:

```
public struct Dzeta
{

}
```

What is more, you can overload operators if you need to:

```
public static Dzeta operator +(Dzeta dz1, Dzeta dz2)
{
   return new Dzeta (/* some operations */);
}
```

You can also overload cast operator, so you could use your class where int is used (cast will by done automatically):

```
public static explicit operator int(Dzeta d)
{
    //return some int
}
```

then

```
int a = new Dzeta(); //implicit cast was made!
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own struct with overloads of basic operators and conversions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from most of classes but not the base types since they are sealed.

take a look at this post:
[c# deriving from int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850306/c-sharp-deriving-from-int32)

It is also a good idea to read about inheritance. you will need it if you want to work with object oriented languages like C# :)

Answer (score 0):

I use extensions and overrides to make classes behave like this.

```
/* A class that behaves a lot like an int */
public class Dzeta
{
    private int __dzeta;
    public Dzeta() { }
    public Dzeta(int i)
    {
        this.__dzeta = i;
    }

    public static Dzeta operator +(Dzeta a, Dzeta b)
    {
        var c = new Dzeta(a.__dzeta + b.__dzeta);
        return c;
    }
    public static Dzeta operator -(Dzeta a, Dzeta b)
    {
        var c = new Dzeta(a.__dzeta - b.__dzeta);
        return c;
    }
    public static Dzeta operator +(Dzeta a, int b)
    {
        var c = new Dzeta(a.__dzeta + b);
        return c;
    }
    public static Dzeta operator -(Dzeta a, int b)
    {
        var c = new Dzeta(a.__dzeta - b);
        return c;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return __dzeta.ToString();
    }

}
/* Extend the int like behaviors of my DZeta class*/
public static class DZExtensions
{
    public static Dzeta Sum(this Dzeta self, params Dzeta[] all)
    {
        var z = new Dzeta();
        foreach (var dz in all)
            z += dz;
        return z;
    }
    public static Dzeta Sum(this Dzeta self, params int[] all)
    {
        var z = new Dzeta();
        foreach (var dz in all)
            z += dz;
        return z;
    }
}



/* This is how it can be used in the application*/
public class UsageOfDZeta
{
    public void DoSomeDZetaWork()
    {
        var zz = new Dzeta(5);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(zz);     // prints 5
        zz += 15;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(zz);     // prints 20
        zz.Sum(10, 5, 20, 5);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(zz);     // prints 60
    }
}
```